Calculate hours based on individual date/month
dataxx



Column 1
Column 2
Column 3
Column 4
Column 5
Column 6
Column 7
Column 8




01-Oct-24

01-Oct-24

01-Oct-24

01-Oct-24



02-Oct-24

02-Oct-24

02-Oct-24

02-Oct-24



03-Oct-24

03-Oct-24

03-Oct-24

03-Oct-24



04-Oct-24
1:01
04-Oct-24

04-Oct-24
7:14
04-Oct-24



05-Oct-24
1:30
06-Oct-24
5:29
06-Oct-24
1:01
06-Oct-24



07-Oct-24

07-Oct-24

07-Oct-24

07-Oct-24



08-Oct-24
5:28
08-Oct-24

08-Oct-24
5:26
08-Oct-24



09-Oct-24

09-Oct-24

09-Oct-24

09-Oct-24



10-Oct-24

10-Oct-24

10-Oct-24

10-Oct-24



11-Oct-24
1:00
11-Oct-24

11-Oct-24
6:00
12-Oct-24
7:00


13-Oct-24
6:30
13-Oct-24

14-Oct-24
6:30
15-Oct-24
0:30



Cannot add hours based on individual date/month due to date in multiple column.
How can i get the following output in excel using function?
output

and


0 values need not to be there.
Sum individual date hours.
Sum individual month hours.
No pivot or pq please.

Thanks

You could try something along the lines of using GROUPBY()


• Output Option One:
=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:H11),2),
     δ, DROP(α,,1),
     GROUPBY(TAKE(α,,1),δ,SUM,,0,,δ<>""))


Or, using MAP()
=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:H11),2),
     δ, TAKE(α,,1),
     φ, DROP(α,,1),
     ε, UNIQUE(δ),
     Σ, MAP(ε, LAMBDA(a, SUM(N(a=δ)*φ))),
     FILTER(HSTACK(ε,Σ),Σ<>0))


• Output Option Two:


=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:H11),2),
     δ, DROP(α,,1),
     GROUPBY(TEXT(TAKE(α,,1),"mmm-yy"),δ,SUM,,0,,δ<>""))


=LET(
     α, WRAPROWS(TOCOL(A1:H11),2),
     δ, TEXT(TAKE(α,,1),"mmm-yy"),
     φ, DROP(α,,1),
     ε, UNIQUE(δ),
     Σ, MAP(ε, LAMBDA(a, SUM(N(a=δ)*φ))),
     FILTER(HSTACK(ε,Σ),Σ<>0))


One should makesure to set the time formatting for the output option 2s as [h]:mm:ss;@

